# How to use Interface or Class to group Common UI events at one place?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is there a way to have all the common UI events in one file. Here is what I have
I have various UserForms in which say i have a close button which closes the form. So instead of writing an event in each form to close. It is possible to have an interfact or something to have this code and we just refer it in the respective form.

Comment: What UI system are you working with? WinForms? WPF? Something more exotic from the Xamarin line?

Comment: What have you already tried? And also in which UI Framework are you working (WinForms, WPF, UWP...)? As the question stands right now it is too broad

Comment: MVC, MVVM, ReactiveUI. Search for them. You should always define the Framework you're using, otherwise is difficult for anybody to even suggest something that makes sense. Anyway, you don't really need to use a specific pre-made pattern. You can build it with the standard tools. You just need some wisely structured support classes.

Comment: I am using a Winform application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a group of controls which are cohesive and work together as a group, I'd suggest creating a [custom control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/creating-a-wf-control-design-time-features).

For your example of a close button, however (why do your forms need one over and above the standard one in the title bar?), what you could use is [*inheritance*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-inherit-windows-forms).

All WinForms forms derive from [`Form`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form?view=netframework-4.7.2). But they don't have to *directly* derive from `Form`. So you could create a "template" form containing all of your common controls, with appropriate positioning, etc.

Then when you create a new form, you go into its code and change

```
public partial class NewForm : Form
```

to

```
public partial class NewForm : TemplateForm
```

The only slight irksome bit of this is that you have to recompile after each change of the template if you want the designer for the derived forms to show up updated layouts correctly.

---

Create a new Windows Forms application. I've chosen C#, .NET Framework, VS 2019.

On Form1, add a button. In it's click event have:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Hello");
}
```

Save your changes, build the project.

Now add `Form2` to the project. Choose "View Code" and edit it's declaration line:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form1
```

Edit `Program.cs` to make `Form2` be the startup form:

```
static void Main()
{
  Application.EnableVisualStyles();
  Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
  Application.Run(new Form2());
}
```

Run the program. You'll see it's `Form2` running, but it has the button from `Form1` and when you click the button, you get the `Hello` message.

Comment: Thank you, Damien! You mean to have a TemplateForm as a separate form and define the events in that?  Sorry, I am not quite getting it. Do you have an example code?

Comment: @SamK - I've added a link from inheritance to one of a set of pages of documentation, but yes, you have a separate form which can contain the controls. It can also contain event handlers, etc, but doesn't *have* to. Those are choices you're free to make. For instance, you can even mix and match - some of the controls in the template have event handlers in the template, some are expected to have handlers provided by the form using the template, some may be optional, etc.

Comment: If I understood correctly, I have to create a user control and create controls dynamically and place them at runtime

Comment: @SamK - added a quick-and-dirty walkthrough of setting it up in a new project

Comment: @SamK- no, custom control was *one* option. The other option is *inheritance* and that's what I'd recommend here for the close button.

Comment: Thanks for the example, I will try and let you know